# OpenVPN server on second router in LAN

Tags: routing, openvpn, openwrt

I have two routers with OpenWRT and I have OpenVPN server on second one. The way from the internet is: router from ISP -> Linksys with OpenWRT -> TP-Link with OpenWRT and OpenVPN server. All routers are in one LAN (192.168.0.1 ISP -> 192.168.0.3 Linksys -> 192.168.0.2 TP-Link). Router from ISP has DMZ set to Linksys. With all of this I can't connect to the server on TP-Link.

Before I added Linksys I had port forwarded from ISP router to TP-Link and then it worked.

I know that redirecting ports now doesn't make sense, because there is one subnet so I have to do this with iptables and DNAT / SNAT. I've tried some entries but I'm probably too stupid to make it work :)

So main problem is: how to redirect packets from Linksys to TP-Link so they can reach OpenVPN server?